# How to repeat a key in AutoHotKey

Tags: automation, macros, autohotkey

I'm trying to use AutoHotKey to solve an accessibility issue, and it's not as automatic as it seems. Basically, I want to make a scrip that allows me to toggle on or off "hold down a key." Ideally this would be any of the letter keys, but I only really need W and X. I don't know the language, but my concept looks like this:

```
when user presses ctrl+caps_lock+w:
send w repeatedly
if user presses ctrl+caps_lock+w: end loop
```

Can anyone show me how to do this? I think it would take a long time to learn.